# Крестики нолики

Tags: java

Пытаюсь реализовать своими силами игру крестики-нолики на Java. Все вроде работает так как задумывалось, но продолжение игры вообще не идет.

Суть в том что метод `Exit()` зацикливается. при вводе "n" все работает хорошо, а при вводе "Y" Спрашивает по новой.

Подскажите,пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

---

```
package tic_tac_toe;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class XO {

    public static void Game(){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // Подключение класса считывания инф-и (аля Read)
        String hole; // переменная местоположения

        String[][] field = new String[3][3];
        // Заполняем массив пробелами, для последущего замещения их Х или О
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                field[i][j] = (" [ ] ");
                System.out.print(field[i][j]);
            }
        }       

        int i = 2;
        int quit=0;
        while((i<11) & (quit == 0)){

            if (i % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println("\nХодит Х");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("\nХодит О");
            }
            System.out.print("Введите клетку:> ");
            // Считывание ввода, и ход.
                switch (hole = in.next()){
                case "7":{
                    if (field[0][0] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[0][0] = (" [X] ");
                            i++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[0][0] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }

                case "8":{
                    if (field[0][1] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[0][1] = (" [X] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[0][1] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }
                case "9":{
                    if (field[0][2] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[0][2] = (" [X] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[0][2] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }
                case "4":{
                    if (field[1][0] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[1][0] = (" [X] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[1][0] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }
                case "5":{
                    if (field[1][1] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[1][1] = (" [X] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[1][1] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }
                case "6":{
                    if (field[1][2] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[1][2] = (" [X] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[1][2] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }
                case "1":{
                    if (field[2][0] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[2][0] = (" [X] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[2][0] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }
                case "2":{
                    if (field[2][1] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[2][1] = (" [X] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[2][1] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }
                case "3":{
                    if (field[2][2] == (" [ ] ")){
                        if (i % 2 == 0){
                            field[2][2] = (" [X] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                        else {
                            field[2][2] = (" [O] ");
                            i++; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Эта клетка занята, введите другую."); break;
                    }
                }
                default:
                    System.out.println("\nОшибка ведите еще раз!");
                    break;
                }
            // Вывод поля на экран
            for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++){
                System.out.println();
                for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++){
                    System.out.print(field[p][l]);
                }
            }
            for (int t = 0; t<3 ; t++){ 
            // Проверка прямых
                if      (((field[t][0]) == " [O] " & (field[t][1]) == " [O] " & field[t][2] == " [O] ") ||
                         ((field[0][t]) == " [O] " & (field[1][t]) == " [O] " & field[2][t] == " [O] ")) {
                    System.out.print("\nПобедил  О ");
                    quit++; Exit();
                }
                else if (((field[t][0]) == " [X] " & (field[t][1]) == " [X] " & field[t][2] == " [X] ") ||
                         ((field[0][t]) == " [X] " & (field[1][t]) == " [X] " & field[2][t] == " [X] ")) {
                    System.out.print("\nПобедил  Х ");
                    quit++; Exit();
                }
                else {}
            }
            // Проверка диагоналей
            if      (((field[0][0]) == " [X] " & (field[1][1]) == " [X] " & field[2][2] == " [X] ") ||
                     ((field[0][2]) == " [X] " & (field[1][1]) == " [X] " & field[2][0] == " [X] ")) {
                System.out.print("\nПобедил  Х ");
                quit++; Exit();
            }
            else if (((field[0][0]) == " [O] " & (field[1][1]) == " [O] " & field[2][2] == " [O] ") ||
                     ((field[0][2]) == " [O] " & (field[1][1]) == " [O] " & field[2][0] == " [O] ")) {
                System.out.print("\nПобедил  О ");
                quit++; Exit();
            }
            else {}
        }
            System.out.println();
        }
    public static void Exit(){ // Отсутствует продолжение игры      
        Scanner ex = new Scanner(System.in);
        String re;
        do {
            System.out.print("Хотите продолжить игру? ");
            re = ex.next();
            if (re == "Y"){
                Game();
            }
            else if(re == "n") {
                break;
            }
        } while (re == ("Y") || re == "n");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game();
        //Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я когда вижу подобный код, возникает вопрос: а если бы поле было 5х5 или 8х8, вы бы таким же диким дублированием кода это  реализовывали?

Comment: @Regent, ну поле 5х5 мне не нужно, мне бы 3х3 сделать для начала, но учту на будущее. Есть идеи как можно это сократить?

Comment: Например, заменить весь `switch - case` на единственный, рассчитывая индексы в `field[1][2]` на основании введённого числа.

Comment: В далеком 1999м я писал крестики-нолики на Visual Basic и тоже копипастил код, потому что не знал, что такое функции или методы. Но вы-то знаете, так пользуйтесь же! )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Строки сравнивают методом `equals(String str)`
То есть у Вас должно быть:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Хотите продолжить игру? ");
    re = ex.next();
    if (re.equals("Y")) {
        Game();
    }
    else if (re.equals("N")) {
        break;
    }
} while (re.equals("N") || re.equals("Y"));
```

А при вводе `"n"` поток выходит из цикла лишь потому, что Вы воспользовались **досрочным выходом** `break` из цикла.

Comment: а вообще, думаю, тебе будет интересно:
Обычно методы в Джаве начинаются с маленькой буквы и содержат в себе глаголы.

Comment: спасибо огромное, учту.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] field = new char[3][3];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("Крестики, введите номер клетки по горизонтали, начиная с 0: ");
            int a = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Крестики, по вертикали: ");
            int b = scanner.nextInt();
            field[a][b] = 'x';

            for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j<3; j++){
                    System.out.print(field[i][j]+" | ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.print("Нолики, введите номер клетки по горизонтали, начиная с 0: ");
            int c = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Нолики, по вертикали: ");
            int d = scanner.nextInt();
            field[c][d] = '0';

            for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j<3; j++){
                    System.out.print(field[i][j]+" | ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }



            if (field[0][0] == field[0][1]&& field[0][1] == field[0][2]&&field[0][2]=='x'||field[0][2]=='y'){
                System.out.println("Победили "+field[0][2]);
                break;
            }

            else if (field[0][0] == field[1][0]&& field[1][0] == field[2][0]&&field[2][0]=='x'||field[2][0]=='y'){
                System.out.println("Победили "+field[0][0]);
                break;
            }

            else if (field[0][1] == field[1][1]&& field[1][1] == field[2][1]&&field[2][1]=='x'||field[2][1]=='y'){
                System.out.println("Победили "+field[0][1]);
                break;
            }

            else if (field[2][0] == field[2][1]&& field[2][1] == field[2][2]&&field[2][2]=='x'||field[2][2]=='y'){
                System.out.println("Победили "+field[2][0]);
                break;
            }

            else if (field[0][2] == field[1][2]&& field[1][2] == field[2][2]&&field[2][2]=='x'||field[2][2]=='y'){
                System.out.println("Победили "+field[0][2]);
                break;
            }

            else if (field[0][0] == field[1][1]&& field[1][1] == field[2][2]&&field[2][2]=='x'||field[2][2]=='y'){
                System.out.println("Победили "+field[0][0]);
                break;
            }

            else if (field[1][0] == field[1][1]&& field[1][1] == field[2][2]&&field[2][2]=='x'||field[2][2]=='y'){
                System.out.println("Победили "+field[1][0]);
                break;
            }

            else if (field[0][2] == field[1][1]&& field[1][1] == field[2][0]&&field[0][2]=='x'||field[0][2]=='y'){
                System.out.println("Победили "+field[0][2]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

По сути тот же код, но просто хочу его показать, ибо это первый более-менее серьёзный "проект" :), хотя еще сырой довольно.

Comment: Вы отвечаете на вопрос или просто показываете код? Суть вопроса, как устранить конкретную ошибку, как я его понял.

Answer (score -1):

Просто добавте `break` после:

```
if (re == "Y") {
    Game();
```